# Change the display name of a scheduled query in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can I edit names of scheduled queries?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using the REST API method [projects.locations.transferConfigs.patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/patch):

1. Set `name` to the resource name of the transfer config. Transfer
   config names have the form of
   `projects/{projectId}/locations/{region}/transferConfigs/{configId}`.
   You can find it at the Configuration tab of the Scheduled query when
   navigating through the Cloud Console, next to **Resource name**.
2. Set `updateMask` to `displayName`.
3. In the **Request body** set the newly desired name with:

   ```
   {
     "displayName": "My new scheduled query name"
   }
   ```

   This will change the scheduled query name to `My new scheduled query name`; replace this value accordingly.
4. Click **Execute** and authorize the call with your account.